# Slack Incoming Web Hooks - Send message ONLY once

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api

I push a lot (10Ks) of messages to Slack channel webhooks each month. It's not uncommon for the Slack API to return network errors, like `ECONNRESET`, meaning I don't know if the message was sent or not.

You can resend (POST) to the Slack [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) endpoint, but that *might* deliver the message twice.

Is there a way to idempotently send a Slack message *once* to a channel using Slack webhooks?

Answer (score 0):

Slack Webhooks provide a very limited set of functionality.
**Idempotency** is not one of them.

https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks